# PowerPoint. How to implement opening exe-file on pressing the image? (Path to this file is known)

Tags: powerpoint

I paste an image to my presentation, and I want an exe-file to be opened when the user clicks on the image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The following code opens an executable. Be sure to change the file path to your desired file path.

```
Sub LaunchExe()

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Proc As Variant

    FilePath = "[your file path here]"      'Example: FilePath = "C:\Windows\Explorer.exe"
    Proc = Shell(FilePath, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Lastly, select the image on  your PowerPoint slide, go to the 'Insert' ribbon and select 'Action'. On the 'Mouse Click' tab, select to 'Run macro' and select the macro.

When the slide is displayed in presentation mode, clicking the image should then open the application.

Use this page to reference the different options as to whether the application opens with focus or not, maximized, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function